# PrintWriter flush not working?

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the following code working so that I can use it somewhere else.

Effectively, it (is supposed to) start another process, run python in it, and feed python some commands. However, in practice, unless I close the stream to that process, the the python commands are never sent. I thought flush() was supposed to force this to happen, but it does not appear to be working. Could anyone provide any insight as to why flush() may not be working and what I could do to avoid this? Thanks.

Note that if I call close() the command is sent. However, I want to be able to send more commands after this one command, so using close() here seems unacceptable. (I'll eventually close() everything)

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Foo {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  Process cmd = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python");

  InputStream inStream = cmd.getInputStream();
  Thread stdout = new Thread(new stdOutReader(inStream));
  stdout.start();

  InputStream errStream = cmd.getErrorStream();
  Thread stderr = new Thread(new stdOutReader(errStream));
  stderr.start();

  OutputStream outStream = cmd.getOutputStream();
  OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(outStream);
  PrintWriter pWriter = new PrintWriter(outStream, true);
  pWriter.println("print \"Testing..\"");

  pWriter.flush();
  int x = 0;
  while (x < 100){
      //Do stuff here (will not be an infinite loop in actual code)
  }

  pWriter.close();

}
private static class stdOutReader implements Runnable{
   InputStream inStream;

   public stdOutReader(InputStream inStream){
       this.inStream = inStream;
   }

   public void run() {
       InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(this.inStream);
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(reader);
       while (scan.hasNext()) {
          System.out.println(scan.next());
          System.out.flush();
       }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried checking code to check for an error?  `PrintWriter` hides those. Perhaps consider using a different IO class that has more robust error handling (if you can't please comment why).

Comment: @noahz I'm not sure what you mean. If I put calls to "checkError" on pWriter before and after the flush, it returns false. If I catch exceptions in main rather than throwing them, I catch none. I've also tried using BufferedWrither (with "write"s rather than "println"s), so I'm not opposed to using different I/O classes.

Comment: The printing looks okay; it is probably the Scanner, which maintains the last token and reads ahead. Try doing it with just an InputStream, reading lines. It is hard to get everything right around Process usage.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Apache Commons Executor](http://commons.apache.org/exec/index.html) instead of using the `Runtime.exec()` API directly.

Comment: I tried this, and it doesn't seem to have made a difference. That being said, when I used this code, I may not have been giving it input correctly.

Comment: Perhaps you need a newline at the end of the text you are sending to python...?

Comment: At this point, perhaps you should be investigating platform-specific behavior, researching open defects in your version of Python, etc. I can't provide additional guidance, however.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see anything wrong with your program Foo. I tested it with a program which echoes input back to output (instead of python), and it works perfectly.